# Selectable TextView in a ListView (Animation missing)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, textview

I built a ListView with a Custom Adapter so that I have a Checkbox (invisible at the time) and a TextView to display some text.

Now I want to have the beautiful animation when selecting an item in the List (Background beeing blue for the time you touch the element). Is this possible?

I already added an OnLongTouchListener and it worked but no animation!

Would be cool to get some help :)

Layout-XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/list_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false">
    </CheckBox>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:clickable="true"
        android:longClickable="true" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Java-Code:

```
private class CommunityListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Community> {

    private List<Community> items;
    private Context context;

    public CommunityListAdapter(Context context, List<Community> communities) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, communities);
        this.items = communities;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        Community item = items.get(position);
        if(item != null) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_text);
            if(textView != null) {
                textView.setText(item.getName());
                textView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                        startActionMode(new MultiChoiseCABListener());
                        Toast.makeText(context, "TEST", 10).show();
                        return false;
                    }

                });
            }
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the Question with some Code inside!

Answer (score 0):

You havent defined animation please define animation and associate with this view.

```
        Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f);
        a.setDuration(1000);
        YOURTEXTVIEW.startAnimation(a);
```

Comment: What does that mean? Can you give me a link to a tutorial or documentation? Sorry, but I just started developing for Android and can't find it.

Comment: I have added the instructions...Plz accept the answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Create pressed state xml in your drawables in which you set different bitmaps to be displayed at different states of tap, and set that xml as your main layout background.

example state xml.

list_item_bg_state.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue_bg" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white_bg"/>
</selector>
```

where blue_bg and white_bg are two.png images in your drawables.

note above xml should be in your drawables folder. Now set this xml as background of your list item main layout. like,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg_state"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

regards,
Aqif

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me! The standard background works without problems, but the clicking does not change anything!